# Problem parsing IP address in Watson Assistant intent

Tags: watson-assistant

I'm working on an assistant to help network engineers.  One of the intents I'm trying to create will allow them to find out information about a device via the IP address.  I created an entity, called @ip, that uses patterns to represent an IP address `(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}`.  I then reference that in my intent examples like:

- show me device @ip
- show me information about @ip

When I try out a phrase `show me device 192.168.1.1` Watson is unable to determine the intent.  Watson does recognize that I've entered an entity of ip that is in IPv4 format.  Note I only have one intent and one entity in the skill at this time.  I have added a node in the dialog for the intent.

[image]

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you select your intent from the dropdown menu and assign it as the correct value? How many test values do you have? The minimum should be 10+. Has Watson Assistant already trained based on the samples?

Comment: When you go in and select the correct intent, it adds the text of what the user typed in as an example.  It effectively ... pollutes the set of examples and effectively makes it looks like the concept of referencing an entity in the examples does not work "show me device 10.10.10.10", "show me device 9.9.9.9". show me device 192.128.1.2".  I've done this with entities that don't use patterns and they don't have the same problem.  I also found if I drop the entity from the intent and putting it in the dialog node it seems to work.  Just not pattern based entities in intents.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the problem, it was an ID10T error. My entity was named device with one of the patterns called `ip`. I've since corrected my example intents to use `@device` instead.